# im trying to send a js array to php using axios formdata but it keep on failing i get [objext object] at console and if im trying to use stringify ""

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, axios

i'm trying to post js array of keys and values to php using axios and am really lost thanks for your help

here is the array i'm sending:

```
 let arr = [];
    arr["adID"] = uuidv4();
    arr["price"] = price;
    arr["city"] = city;
    arr["street"] = street;
    arr["rooms"] = rooms;
    arr["building_number"] = building_number;
    arr["entry"] = entry;
    arr["apartment"] = apartment;
    arr["user_id"] = 1;
    sendDataFromJsToPhp("insertAd", arr);
```

here is the axios part:

```
 sendDataFromJsToPhp(type, parametersArray) {
this.formData.append("data", "insertAd"); //type to create new ad is insertAd
this.formData.append(
  "parameters",parametersArray); //type to create new ad is insertAd
axios({
  method: "post",
  url: this.url,
  data: this.formData,
  config: { headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" } },
}).then(
  (response) => {
    console.log(response.data);
    this.resultFromServer = response.data;
  },
  (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  }
);
//this is a work around that will get us array of keys and one of values and will merge them
//to get aray that represent the data we got
return this.resultFromServer;
```

}

here is the php:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *");
header('Content-Type: application/json');


$DATA_RAW = file_get_contents("php://input");


$DATA_OBJ = json_decode($DATA_RAW);
$error = "";
 if(isset($_POST)&&isset($_POST['data']))
$dataType = $_POST["data"];
if(isset($_POST)&&isset($_POST['parameters']))
$parameters=$_POST['parameters'];
print_r($parameters);
```

the errors present when i address the $parameters i get these errors:
1)**Warning**:  Uninitialized string offset 0 in 
**2)b>Fatal error**:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string in

thank you very much

Comment: Why are you creating an array (_named `arr`_) then treating it like an object? Sure you can add arbitrary properties to an array (it's an object underneath), but not in _JSON_ - only the values by _index_ get serialised. Why not _start with an object_?

Comment: Also you're not sending JSON, not I'm not sure why you've told php to try and decode any JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your array uses a string key value, instead of an int, **stringify ignores that value.**

Hence you have to create an object instead of array.

ie;

```
let arr = {};
    arr.adID = uuidv4();
    arr.price = price;
    arr.city = city;
    arr.street = street;
    arr.rooms = rooms;
    arr.building_number = building_number;
    arr.entry = entry;
    arr.apartment = apartment;
    arr.user_id = 1;
    sendDataFromJsToPhp("insertAd", arr);
```

And in the formData append;

```
this.formData.append(
  "parameters", JSON.stringify(parametersArray)); //type to create new ad is insertAd
```

Comment: thank you, i'm still not succeeding to get the array data inside the php, maybe you can help me? i have tried $_POST['parameters'] and it is still giving  me  [object,object] ,thank you

Comment: @user16365106 It should work fine if you make the changes I said. Make sure you added the JSON.stringify just like I mentioned. Check the network tab in the developer console -> payload(or request) -> your data should be there